# Is Karkaroff's first name (Igor) an allusion to Frankenstein?

Tags: harry-potter, literary-analysis

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_%28fictional_character%29) sayeth:

> Igor (or sometimes Ygor) is the traditional stock character or cliché hunch-backed assistant or butler to many types of villain, such as Count Dracula or a Dr. Victor Frankenstein, familiar from many horror movies and horror movie parodies, the Universal Studios Frankenstein series and the film Van Helsing in particular.

Since this seems like a standard, was there any confirmation from Rowling that Karkaroff's first name is related to the cliché, given both his role in the books (ex-helper to Voldemort, AND a moral hunch-back)? (never mind **Viktor** Krum's given name :)

Comment: IMO, there's not much resemblance in the characters (beyond helper to Vi[ck]tor). Dr. Frankenstein's assistant helped bring a monster into the world, Karkaroff was a weakling who sought a more powerful wizard, reneged when said wizard disappeared, and fled when he returned.

Comment: Unfortunately unless Rowling says "I based Karkaroff's name from the Frankenstein movies" then the answer cannot be yes because speculation isn't canon. And to be fair, we can't really say No either, unless she explicitly says that she definately didn't base it on Frankenstein films. Personally, though, I see little resemblance between them apart from them both being vaguely Germanic (in which place Vic-k-tor and Igor are common enough names anyway); but that's just my opinion, as there is no canonical answer. If anything, perhaps she took the name just from looking for a creepy Germanic name.

Comment: @MacCooper - if you haven't notice, the question is very explicitly worded as "was there any confirmation from Rowling".

Comment: No, I know that. But I figured you'd like a bit of a tally of the possibilities, else frankly you could have just gone onto her faq. My comment did not discount your question, unless your comment is in regards to the very first part of my answer which was a bit of an introduction. So, if you want your question answered explicitly as possible: No, she has not said that she based it on Frankenstein films. I didn't think "No" would be incredibly helpful so I tried digging into the question a bit. I did answer your question in fact: "There is no canonical answer" ie, she has neither said yes or no

Comment: @MacCooper - "her faq"? - For your reference, JKR produced around 100s of interviews of all sorts, site FAQs, AND Pottermore. Would you care to explain how I "could have just gone onto her faq" for that?

Comment: Okay, that's fair enough, I shouldn't have said that, it was rather rude, I apologise. Ignoring that part of my answer though, and reiterating my point a bit less rudely: I did answer your question. I had a dig around and found no answer from her either way, so I told you that, and then, to be helpful, I elaborated and went into (my opinion of course) of the possibility of the reference. Sorry for the snappiness though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget the movies, go right to the source.  I just started reading the original 'Frankenstein'... and was very surprised, when the name 'Nicolas Flamel' came up. Nicolas Flamel happens to be a real alchemist who was born at the right time (ca 1330 AD) to be THE Nicolas Flamel in Harry Potter.

In addition to this, one of the things that Victor Frankenstein is looking for is, "...the philospher's stone and the elixir of life;"  Ch 2 pg 26 - paperback 1973 edition.

One thing can be a coincidence... two... then three.. not so much so.  And 'Nicolas Flamel' and "the philospher's stone" can not be coincidences.

Even if Rowling has not openly confirmed it, thus making it canon, there is definitely a connection between the two books.

Comment: Nicolas Flamel and the Philosopher's stone is *one* coincidence. It's a real person and the mythical thing they were trying to create. This is clearly two separate books inspired by the same thing, not one book inspired by the other.

Answer (score 12):

Igor is a common name in countries which have slavic languages, I wouldn't read much into it for example if there was a British character named Richard you wouldn't automatically assume it's a reference to Richard Lionheart.

Comment: 1. Slavic; 2. Drumstrang is supposed to be in Norway or Sweden, neither of which is Slavic in the list. Also, if there was a British character named Richard who was a hunchback, i'd assume it was a reference to Richarc the IIId.

Comment: They don't state Karkaroff comes from the country which the school is based in. Doesn't Hoggwarts have foreign teachers? Hm, now I think about it, I can't come up with one. But they could have had. @DVK

Comment: Yes but he name is still very widely used even if not in the area Durmstrang is and seeing as Viktor is from a slavic country as well it's pretty clear that those countries ship all their wizards to Durmstrang. Now if Viktor was German as opposed to Bulgarian yes I would say that the 2 names were references.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Victor is Bulgarian, which is Slavic.